# JavaScript scripts do not work at the same time, even if they have nothing to do with each other

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I want both JavaScript scripts to work smoothly, the first:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function()
{
     $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
});
```

second:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
```

I want to mention that if I leave only a script, it works without problems. How can I make both scriptures work?

Comment: Depends where you are putting your .dropdown click listener. You could add it into your ready function which should work fine.

Comment: Is the tag with class '.dropdown' inside of your table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge them to one piece:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').click(function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');
    });
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
```

Comment: only the following code snippet works
$ ( '# MyTable'). Datatable (); and the dropdown button does not work

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the full code please?

Comment: I made a small mistake and I didn't close a tag, and your solution helped me

Comment: glad to help :)